# How to change the app switching keyboard shortcut from the standard Cmd + Tab key to Cmd + Eject key combo?

Tags: keyboard, application-switcher

I would like to change the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> hotkey to <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Eject</kbd>.

I use a Mac Aluminium keyboard with the eject key, which is only present on external keyboards.

I would like to try this key combination, or other possibly, to avoid the excessive amount of <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>s I do every day; and even maybe prevent a future RSI.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a keyboard customiser app like [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) to tweak the default key associations.

Karabiner is a free software.